# How to do group by and divide in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

df:

```
Id  items    Sales  Qty
1   Shoes    300    5
2   Clothes  900    8
3   Woods    600    7
4   Shoes    800    4

main_Id = 5
```

I want to group by the dataframe based on the condition on Id and   main_Id. Now the diff between max of Id i.e 4 and the main_Id i.e 5 is one. Then I have to group by my df only once and append  records in df, if it is 2 I need to group by twice and so on...
I tried:

```
max_id_df =int(df.Id.astype(int).max())
diff = main_Id - max_id_df
if diff==1:
   df2= df.groupby(items).['Sales','Qty'].sum().reset_index()
    df.append(df2, ignore_index = True) 
elif diff==2:
    df2= df.groupby(items).['Sales','Qty'].sum().reset_index()
    df.append(df2, ignore_index = True)--- 1st groupby
    df3= df.groupby(items).['Sales','Qty'].sum().reset_index()
    df.append(df3, ignore_index = True)--- 2ndst groupby
```

I want this thing to be dynamic, I have hard coded till diff ==2. Diff can be of any number. Is there a way of doing this thing in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following. Create a dictionary and save all dataframes that will be created by grouping, with their respective name. This way you will ease the naming of the dataframes and the general structure of your code:

```
dfs={}
k=2
for _ in range(diff):
    dfs['df'+str(k)]=df.groupby(items).['Sales','Qty'].sum().reset_index()
    df.append(dfs['df'+str(k)], ignore_index = True) 
    k+=1
```